# Given a vector of objects, what's the quickest a range can be looked up?

Tags: algorithm, performance, complexity-theory, kdtree

I have a vector of objects with fields min_length and max_length, I'd like to do a range look up on all the objects where length >= min_length and <= max length.

Performance is very critical so ideally I need to be able to do this in O(log n), is it possibile?

I can't use any existing libraries so need to build this using just the basics.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not clear on the data structure and desired result.
How do  you intend to return **O(n)** objects in **O(log n)** time?

Comment: So let's say it's a dating app, and you say you're happy to date someone between 25 and 30. A person then comes a long and puts in their search, they want to lookup all potential matches, given their age 28. The system could manually loop through each potential match where min_age < 28, then check if max_age is > 28, but that would require looping through every potential match, which is too slow.

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to ask.  I'm trying to understand the whole problem.  For sake of illustration, let there be one million people in the data base, 10% of whom are in the 25-30 age range.  You put in the query and it somehow identifies those 100.000 people.  What mechanism do you envision that might allow you to return those **n/10** matches in **O(log n)** time?  I don't see how you can have those records transferable in less than **O(n)** time, given that you have multiple selection criteria.

Comment: I'm talking about the actual lookup time of those matches, e.g I could go through each entry manually, or if they're sorted do a binary search, which would be much faster. The issue is, a standard BST wouldn't work here. So, What I'm asking is, is there a way to search and sort all the people so that I can find all potential matches very quickly.

Comment: My first reaction is to have the records sorted independently by min and max values: two separate sequences.  Search each sequence (log n) yielding two lists.  Take the intersection of the two lists -- which is **O(n)** under the given (lack of) structures.

Comment: I suspect that KD-tree will get you an advantage in reality, if not complexity as well.

Comment: Take a look at the [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) or [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).